# Detect actions on window.print() & Iframe toolbar

Tags: angular, iframe, frontend, matchmedia

hello everybody I would like to:

1. Make the difference between: Print & Cancel click when using **window.print()** ?
2. Detect the print-click coming from an **iframe toolbar=1**?

This is what I've been tried without succes:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-window-before-print-event-w1xulg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Bad news... all what you can do is in your code example.

You cannot do more. You haven't access to chromes print dialog window from any website and it send no response which button you clicked...